# FLRW metrics (isotropic and homogeneous space)

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

Consider a [spacetime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Mathematics_of_spacetimes) with metric 
$$ ds^2 = -dt^2 + a^2(t)d\Omega_k^2, \quad k=0,\pm1$$
where $a(t)$ is any regular function and $d\Omega_k^2$ is the 3-dimensional metric of

- the 3-sphere $S^3$, if $k=1$.
- the flat 3-space $\Bbb{R}^3$, if $k=0$.
- the hyperbolic 3-space $H^3$, if $k=-1$.

Questions: what is the Ricci tensor $R_{\mu\nu}$ of this metric and what is $a(t)$ to be in order to have
$$ G_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}=0,$$
for some $\Lambda\in\Bbb{R}$ ?

Comment: For $G_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}=0$, wouldn't you just have to have a vacuum (i.e. $T_{\mu\nu}=0$)?